# falcon api stream vs bounded_stream vs get_media

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, falconframework

Could someone help me to understand the difference between the various methods:

1. `request.bounded_stream.read()`
2. `request.stream.read()`
3. `request.get_media()`

They seem to do the same thing, but using stream or bounded_stream provides a bytes like object.

```
class test_dev(object):
    async def on_post(self, request, response):
        obj = await request.bounded_stream.read()
        print(obj)

class test_dev(object):
    async def on_post(self, request, response):
        obj = await request.stream.read()
        print(obj)

class test_dev(object):
    async def on_post(self, request, response):
        obj = await request.get_media()
        print(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

`stream` and `bounded_stream` are file-like wrappers to access the request body data stream coming from the server. Those are non-seakable and, as far as I know, there is no possibility to peek them either.

The difference between them is that the latter is bound to the `content_length` of the request where `stream` might behave differently from system to system. This is detailed in the [official documentation](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/request_and_response.html#falcon.Request.stream).

As for `get_media()`, it's a wrapper for the `media` property. From the [documentation](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/request_and_response.html#falcon.Request.media), you can read:

> Warning:
>
> This operation will consume the request stream the first time it’s called and cache the results. Follow-up calls will just retrieve a cached version of the object.

So, the first time you access `request.media`, the request stream is consumed and cached, meaning that from that moment on `stream` and `bounded_stream` will return and empty data stream. By default, the application will assume the content type is `application/json` and uses the `json` library to serialize and deserialize the content.

What is not so clear from the docs, but also happens, is that if you choose to access, and therefore consume, `stream` or `bounded_stream`, then accessing `media` will return an error.
If you choose to access `stream` or `bounded_stream` yourself you'll also have to store the data consume yourself.